# Nominal Attributes in LibSVM

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

When creating a libsvm training file, how do you differentiate between a nominal attribute verses a numeric attribute? I'm trying to encode certain nominal attributes as integers, but I want to ensure libsvm doesn't misinterpret them as numeric values. Unfortunately, libsvm's site seems to have very little documentation. [Pentaho's docs](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/LibSVM) seem to imply libsvm makes this distinction, but I'm still not clear how it's made.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't do this** `I'm trying to encode certain nominal attributes as integers`.

Rather, use a separate binary feature for each value of each nominal attribute.

The way SVMs are formulated, all attributes/features are numeric and class labels are nominal. Nominal attributes are essentially faked by using mutually exclusive binary features.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant do that in libsvm, weka or SVM-light. One approach that you could use is to use something like a decision tree for your nominal attributes and svm or any distance based classifier for your numeric attributes and then combine the results. I hope it helps.